# PowerShell Class; property "System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary"; how to add dictionary entry

Tags: powershell, class, dictionary, addition

(As I have searched the web quite intensively for an answer and didn't get any hint in the right direction, I allow myself to ask you the following question:)

I have a PowerShell class like this:

```
class settings
{
    [string]$CFG_Name
    [string]$CFG_Template_Path
    [string]$CFG_Target_Path
    [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]$ConfigSettings
}
```

I then instantiate this class and want to use it like this:

```
$CurrentSettings = New-Object settings    <-- works fine
$CurrentSettings.CFG_Name = 'MPD'    <-- works fine
$CurrentSettings.CFG_Template_Path = $CFG_Template_MPD_Path    <-- works fine
$CurrentSettings.CFG_Target_Path = $CFG_MPD_Path    <-- works fine

$CurrentSettings.ConfigSettings.Add("TID",$EFT_TID)    <-- doesn't work
```

The line above throws: **You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.**

According to this page: [Documentation from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) the add method is supported.

Why can't I just use this property like I can use for example $CFG_Name?

How would I add dictionary entries to this property?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862361/how-to-add-key-value-pair-at-the-end-of-hash-table

Comment: I can't see where in the world that should be a duplicate of my question. Has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following:

Before the adding of the first dictionary entry, you have to initialize the property like this:

```
$CurrentSettings.ConfigSettings = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
```

Then you can add the entry:

```
$CurrentSettings.ConfigSettings.Add("TID",$EFT_TID)
```

Comment: You can also do `.ConfigSettings = [ordered]@{ TID = $EFT_TID }`